# Inverse transform of a point when canvas is transformed

Tags: android, canvas, view

I have a View that can be scaled, rotated and translated. So far all ok, but the touch event returns X,Y  related to the screen.

Is there a way to automatically transform the coordinates so they match the current transformation? I know how to do it manually but I wonder if the SDK provides an automatic method.

Comment: use Matrix.mapPoints method

Comment: I want the reverse process.

Comment: use (inversed Matrix).mapPoints then